# how to use ffmpeg with php and upload and compress the file

Tags: php, video, upload, ffmpeg

hello all i have successfully installed the ffmpeg inmy local computer and now i wanted to know how to use it when uploading the files by php to the server .
i want all the files uploaded by user to be converted to swf format.
i have also incresed my upload limit by php.ini so there is no issue of the upload_mx_size

till now i was using this code

```
 <?php

$srcFile = "test/Sample.mp4";
$destFile = "/test/Sample22";
$ffmpegPath = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg";
$flvtool2Path = "/usr/local/bin/flvtool2";

// Create our FFMPEG-PHP class
$ffmpegObj = new ffmpeg_movie($srcFile);
// Save our needed variables
$srcWidth = makeMultipleTwo($ffmpegObj->getFrameWidth());
$srcHeight = makeMultipleTwo($ffmpegObj->getFrameHeight());
$srcFPS = $ffmpegObj->getFrameRate();
$srcAB = intval($ffmpegObj->getAudioBitRate()/1000);
$srcAR = $ffmpegObj->getAudioSampleRate();
$srcVB = floor($ffmpegObj->getVideoBitRate()/1000); 

// Call our convert using exec() to convert to the three file types needed by HTML5
exec($ffmpegPath . " -i ". $srcFile ." -vcodec libx264 -vpre hq -vpre ipod640 -b ".$srcVB."k -bt 100k -acodec libfaac -ab " . $srcAB . "k -ac 2 -s " . $srcWidth . "x" . $srcHeight . " ".$destFile.".mp4");

exec($ffmpegPath . " -i ". $srcFile ." -vcodec libvpx -r ".$srcFPS." -b ".$srcVB."k -acodec libvorbis -ab " . $srcAB . " -ac 2 -f webm -g 30 -s " . $srcWidth . "x" . $srcHeight . " ".$destFile.".webm");

exec($ffmpegPath . " -i ". $srcFile ." -vcodec libtheora -r ".$srcFPS." -b ".$srcVB."k -acodec libvorbis -ab " . $srcAB . "k -ac 2 -s " . $srcWidth . "x" . $srcHeight . " ".$destFile.".ogv");

?>
```

dont know this is good or not but it dosent works when i just refresh this page the page says

```
 "Fatal error: Class 'ffmpeg_movie' not found in     C:\xampp\htdocs\video\videoupload.php on line 9"
```

i have checked the file sample.mp4 exists into test folder
please help me upload the video files and convert it into swf format by ffmpeg lib

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing a module, uses php -m or phpinfo() to see if you have a module called 'FFmpeg-PHP' installed. If it is missing you will need to install it if you want to use that class

Comment: i have installed ffmpeg i have checked it by my cmd line

Comment: great, have you installed the _php module_ called 'ffmpeg-php' ?

Comment: how do i check that ?

Comment: 'php -m' from your terminal will list installed modules, installed module information is also included in the output of phpinfo()

Comment: yes !!! you are right i am missing module i have checked my php.ini . can you suggest me something where i may get help to insatll the module ..